# Создаю телеграм бота по гайду пытаюсь ввести getMessageId() выдает ошибку

Tags: java, telegram-bot

код

```
public BotApiMethod<?> answerCallbackQuery(CallbackQuery callbackQuery) {
    return EditMessageText.builder()
        .chatId(callbackQuery.getMessage().getChatId())
        .messageId(callbackQuery.getMessage().getMessageId())
        .text("""
                 л
                        """)
        .build();
```

Ошибка.

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getMessageId()
  location: interface org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.MaybeInaccessibleMessage
```